# Variation of a Maximum_Subarray_Problem

Tags: arrays, algorithm

This is a variation of a [Maximum_subarray_problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).

Find contiguous subarray of length at most K, in an array of length N ( 0 <= K <= N )

**Eg. given `[-13,-1,1,1,2,3,1,1]` and `K = 2`, maximum K-subarray sum is 5**

Looking for **O(N)** solution. The trivial solution is O(N*N), checking range between each pair. I feel it can be improved to O(N).

Comment: @Michal It should be trivial to extend Kadane's algorithm from the Wikipedia link you provided to work here.

Comment: @Daniel This is not a duplicate. The difference is that here the length of subarray is limited to K

Comment: @Dukeling I've tried with modifications of Kadane's algorithm, but no success. Could you give me some tips?

Comment: Okay, it's maybe not quite trivial... (I'll think about it some more)

Comment: N log N isn't too hard. Why do you think that there's a linear-time algorithm?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Just common sense. If O(N) is not possible please provide a proof.

Comment: It *is* possible, so no proof forthcoming.

Comment: Voting to reopen because it is *not* a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your array be indexed with 1 to n. Let *f(i)* be the maximum subarray that ends at *i* and *prefixSum(i)* be the prefix sum up to (and including) index *i*. Then we have

> f(i) = prefixSum(i) - MIN(j = i - K to i - 1, prefixSum(j))

f(i) can be computed in linear time by using a [sliding window minimum](http://people.cs.uct.ac.za/~ksmith/articles/sliding_window_minimum.html) data structure. [Here's another implementation](https://github.com/niklasb/contest-algos/blob/master/monotonic_queue.cpp) of the queue, it support *enqueue*, *dequeue* and *find-max/min*. Using that queue as a primitive, the algorithm would look like this in pseudocode:

```
global_max = -infinity
prefixSum[0] = 0
q = new MinQueue()
for i := 1 to n:
    prefixSum[i] = prefixSum[i - 1] + a[i]
    if i > 1
        q.enqueue(prefixSum[i - 1])
    if i - K - 1 >= 1
        q.dequeue()
    global_max = max(global_max, prefixSum[i] - q.min())
```

Comment: Do you mean `g[0] = a[0]`? (Otherwise you seem to be leaving `a[0]` out.)

Comment: @ooga I'm assuming one-based indexing here

Comment: What about `g[0]` then?

Comment: @ooga g[i] is the prefix sum of the prefix 1..i, so g[0] is the sum of an empty set

Comment: @NiklasB. What is the difference between g and f?

Comment: @MichalWegorek I renamed g to prefixSum but forgot to replace one occurence.Fixed

Answer (score 0):

This is Java code that performing the same task in O(n)

```
public void maxSubSet (int[] array, int k)
 {
    int startIndex = -1;
    int max = 0;

    for(int i =0; i<k; i++){  //Assuming k<array.length
        max += array[i];
        startIndex = 0;  
    }

    for(int i=k; i<array.length; i++){
        int sum = array[i] - array[i-k]; 
        if (sum > max){
            max = sum; 
            startIndex = i; 
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Max Sum:" + max);
    for(int i = startIndex; i<startIndex+k; i++)
        System.out.println(i+":"+array[i]);
}
```